# Javascript: Find the larger array and return both the smaller and larger array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of unequal length. How do I find and return both, the larger array and the smaller array in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 1):

The following function returns an object which contains the larger and smaller array.

```
const largerAndSmaller = (arr1, arr2) => 
  arr1.length > arr2.length ? {larger: arr1, smaller: arr2} : 
{larger: arr2, smaller: arr1}

let {larger, smaller} = largerAndSmaller([2,1,3],[7,2,3,9]);
```

The caller can then destructure the returned value.